# Show that $\Gamma_{F,G}(T) ^{\perp}= \Gamma_{G,F}(T^t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Show that $\Gamma_{F,G}(T) ^{\perp}= \Gamma_{G,F}(T^t)$, where $T \in L(F,G)$, $T^t \in L(G,F)$,
$$\Gamma_{F,G}(T)=\{u\oplus Tu: \ u \in F\} \ \mbox{and} \ \Gamma_{G,F}(T)=\{u\oplus T^t u: \ u \in G\}$$
are the graphs of $T$ and $T^t$, respectly, $T$ is a linear transform and $T^t$ its transpose. Furthermore,
$$F\oplus G=R^n$$
where $F$ and $G$ are subpaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $m$ and $n-m$, respectly.

I am trying use the propetier of linear algebraic $\operatorname{im}(T)^{\perp}=\ker(T^t)$.